# Opacity not working for overlay

Tags: css

I am trying to create a popup overlay but I can't get the blue overlay to be opaque. The red shows through.

```
<a href="www.google.com">hi</a>
<div class="dim">
    <div class="test">
        <div> test </div>
        <div> 2nd </div>        
    </div>
</div>​

.dim {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.test {
    opacity: 1.0;
    border: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

​
[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NVa65/9/)

Comment: That's the normal behaviour. Child elements will inherit the parent's opacity and there is no way to make them more opaque than the parent. You will need to work with 2 separate elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you html as -

```
<a href="www.google.com">hi</a>
<div class="dim">   
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div> test </div>
    <div> 2nd </div>        
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NVa65/11/)

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is to do a copy-and paste, putting .dim outside of .test.

http://jsfiddle.net/NVa65/10/

From

```
<a href="www.google.com">hi</a>
<div class="dim">
    <div class="test">
        <div> test </div>
        <div> 2nd </div>        
    </div>
</div>​
```

To

```
<a href="www.google.com">hi</a>
<div class="dim">

</div>
<div class="test">
    <div> test </div>
    <div> 2nd </div>        
</div>
​
```